# PHP time() and strtotime() Difference in DST

Tags: php, time, strtotime, dst

Just a quick one. On my site I have a couple of different methods of storing the date in the database. For automatically created dates (i.e. signup time etc.) I use time().

But for manually entered dates I use `strtotime()`.

The problem is, with `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` `strtotime()` is correct but `time()` is an hour behind.

And vice versa `date_default_time_set('Europe/London')` `time()` is correct but `strtotime()` is an hour behind.

I need both to be right, in a way I don't have to change my code when we leave DST. What is the best way to go about this.

Cheers,
RJ

Comment: `time()` will always generate a UNIX timestamp whose timezone is UTC. See [this demo](http://viper-7.com/EG4TEX).

Comment: What are you putting inside `strtotime()`?

Comment: I'm assuming you know that you're only specifying a date, not time with seconds, and you will never get the same result?

Comment: Yes the time tends to default to 00:00:00 which is great because it's the exact date. But with `date_default_time_set('Europe/London')` it is an hour behind, so the day before. So the best option may be to just use Europe/London and use `strtotime('dd/mm/yyyy 01:00:00')`, but what will happen when we leave daylight saving?